# How to cross-build GZIP?

Tags: embedded, gzip, cross-compiling

I am trying to build `gzip` for an embedded platform on a Linux machine. I downloaded the latest gzip distribution from [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gzip/). Then, `make` requires first to run the `configure` program in order to tailor a `Makefile` for the specific target.

So I run `configure` and get some error messages. The problem seems to be a combination of a few things. Our compiler version is called `e-gcc`, so I used the following line, and got this error:

```
~/Projects/gzip-1.4$ ./configure CC=e-gcc
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... e-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/home/xyz/Projects/gzip-1.4':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details.
```

Obviously, C compiled programs cannot run, b/c it is  cross-compiler. The message say I have to use the `--host` option, but the problem is that we don't really have a defined name in gcc. However, I tried:

```
./configure CC=e-gcc --host=epiphany
```

and the error received is:

```
configure: WARNING: If you wanted to set the --build type, don't use --host.
    If a cross compiler is detected then cross compile mode will be used.
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c

blah blah blah

checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... Invalid configuration `epiphany': machine `epiphany' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/bash build-aux/config.sub epiphany failed
```

Last thing, I tried cheating and setting the host to `arm` as it is closest in spirit to our architecture. The configuration went much further, but eventually failed as well with the following message:

```
checking for GNU libc compatible realloc... no
checking for rmdir... no
configure: error: in `/home/xyz/Projects/gzip-1.4':
configure: error: Your system lacks the rmdir function.
              Please report this, along with the output of "uname -a", to the
              bug-coreutils@gnu.org mailing list.  To continue past this point,
              rerun configure with SKIP_RMDIR_CHECK=yes.
              E.g., ./configure SKIP_RMDIR_CHECK=yes
See `config.log' for more details.
```

I am now pretty clueless on how to continue. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try running with the 
SKIP_RMDIR_CHECK=yes
directive?

Comment: Thanks. This indeed enabled the finish of the configuration. We took a different path anyway so this is less important now. I just wonder (and it is not easy to tell from the big makefile) what ARM specific setting were included there. Anyway with that ARM makefile I can start the build but it falls on a header file error (not related to the configure program, though).

Answer (score 5):

Does the embedded platform have an environment in which a command-line gzip program makes sense?  If you want to do gzip compression and decompression from software that you're writing for the embedded platform, then you should consider [zlib](http://zlib.net/) instead.

Comment: The answer is - somewhat. We do have support for standard I/O when working with GDB. The ultimate goal is to partition the application such as the I/O part is done on a host, but to begin with, I tried a plain build of the program on the embedded environment. Thanks for pointing out zlib. From a first look, it seems like a project unrelated to gzip, right? But it does support the gzip compression algorithms, so I can write a utility that decodes/codes any file coded/to-be-decoded by gzip - is that right?

Comment: zlib is very related to gzip, written by the same authors.  And yes, you can use it to compress and decompress gzip streams compatible with the gzip utility.

Answer (score 0):

OK, Thanks, very helpful, it gave me the clues I needed.
I have gone a little further in that I now have a more correct --host string :

--host=eIII-parallella-epiphany

so I call configure as :
./configure CC=/cygdrive/[MYPATH]/Parallella/INSTALL/bin/e-gcc --host=eIII-parallella-epiphany

However you need to do a few other things, including copying the config.sub script from the epiphany sources into your own configure space. I also had to do some other edits, so that MACHOS was defined.
see : http://forums.parallella.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=337&p=2014#p2014  for more details.

cheers, Beau Webber